# Lock .user.js files with .htpasswd

Tags: javascript, php, apache, .htaccess, .htpasswd

I want lock my user js file with basic auth(apache).
I create basic auth with .htaccess & .htpasswd, it work with folder & txt files, but it doesn't work for js files.
Js files are override this protectiont. How to fix it? Thank you for help

Comment: you cannot protect JS files from being viewed if they're used by browser. period.

Comment: @MehulMohan i can laock all files. I can't lock only .js files. I don't wont to use it in <script> tag. I want to download it througth url(like http://mywebsite.com/kek.user.js)

Answer (score 2):

Create a `.htaccess` file in the same directory as that of your JS files. And place this in `.htaccess` file:

```
<FilesMatch "script.js">
AuthName "Member Only"
AuthType Basic
AuthUserFile /home/path/to/your/.htpasswd
require valid-user
</FilesMatch>
```

Comment: Nice solution +1

Comment: `<FilesMatch "script.user.js">
   AuthType Basic
   AuthName "ENTER LOG & PASS FOR ACCESS SCRIPT"
   AuthUserFile /var/www/user67505/data/www/website.com/.htpasswd
   require valid-user
</FilesMatch>
<Files .htpasswd>
   deny from all 
</Files>`

it doesn't work :(

Comment: OH, i fix it!! Thank you!!

Comment: @АлександрЛимаренко you can accept answers by clicking green arrow